# How can I view git diff for any commit using vim-fugitive?

Tags: vim, git-diff, vimdiff, vim-fugitive

vim-fugitive side-by-side git diff is great for viewing diff of unstaged files.

How can I use vim-fugitive to git diff

- staged files?
- any git revision?

Comment: Did you read `:h fugitive`?

Comment: The question was about how to get :Gstatus + D like functionality for any revision. Edited question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Diff between current file and the index

```
:Gdiff :0
```

Diff between current file and some other [revision]

```
:Gdiff [revision]
```

Diff between current file and current file 3 commits ago:

```
:Gdiff ~3
```

Comment: For :Gdiff i need to know the files which were changed in a revision. :Gstatus lists uncommitted files on which i can press D to view the diff. How can i get similar file list and diff on any revision. :Gstatus revision doesn't work!

Comment: I feel like this is the wrong way to approach the problem. You can use `:Glog --` to populate the `quickfix` window with previous commits and explore the commits. I would highly suggest you take a look at the vimcast series on fugitive: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/

Comment: These all operate on a single file. If you can stomach the native output of Git, take a look at `:Git!`. For example, `:Git! show [revision]` will load a syntax-highlight patch of _all_ files in `[revision]`. It's not as nice as the custom interaction model of `:Gstatus`, but can be a handy reference in a split.

Comment: Once you've staged your changes and are typing the commit message inside `Gcommit` I believe the correct command you want is `:Gvdiff ~1` this creates a vertical split which I find easier to see the differences and also more space efficient as the top pane is then still your commit message and your diff is a vertical split below that

Comment: @icc97 you can also do `:Gcommit --verbose` or `cvc` from the `:Gstatus` window.

Comment: adding to @Bluu 's comment above, the output of `:Git show [commithash]` is actually somewhat interactive. Presing ENTER on a diff summary line for example will give a side-by-side diff of the file. more at http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-browsing-the-git-object-database/

Answer (score 41):

You can use `:Glog` to get the history changes for current file. You can use `:cnext` or `:cprevious` to move between changes. When you hit the version that you want to compare then you can use `:Gdiff`. You can exit from vimdiff closing the buffer `:q` and exit from history log with `:Gedit`.

This is my .vimrc keyboard config:

```
  nnoremap <leader>gs :Gstatus<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gc :Gcommit -v -q<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>ga :Gcommit --amend<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gt :Gcommit -v -q %<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gd :Gdiff<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>ge :Gedit<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gr :Gread<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gw :Gwrite<CR><CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gl :silent! Glog<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gp :Ggrep<Space>
  nnoremap <leader>gm :Gmove<Space>
  nnoremap <leader>gb :Git branch<Space>
  nnoremap <leader>go :Git checkout<Space>
  nnoremap <leader>gps :Dispatch! git push<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>gpl :Dispatch! git pull<CR>
```

I recommend `unimpaired.vim` plugin by Tim Pope.

With that configuration, my workflow is:

`<Leader>gl` to view history

`]q` and `[q` to move between versions (unimpaired.vim)

`<Leader>gd` to open `diff`

`:q` to end `diff`

`<Leader>ge` to return to my working copy.

Comment: also requires vim-dispatch

Comment: For those looking at this on 2023. The right command to look at the previous versions of the file is "0Gclog" (instead of Glog), then do Gdiff

Answer (score 14):

Adding to above answer:

If you want to get a diff, of a particular file from another branch

```
Gdiff branch_name:path/to/dir/filename.txt
```

Comment: You can also go `Gdiff <branch>` on a buffer if the same file is also present in the <branch>.

Answer (score 4):

I just drop here the way I view a diff if the `:Glog --` or `:Glog -- %` (for current file) is used:

1. `:Glog --`
2. `:cw` to open a list of commits
3. Navigate to a commit and its info as well affected files are shown
4. Focus on a file path
5. `<c-w>gf` and the diff is opened in new tab
6. `:tabclose` to just close the tab and get the previous state before the diff

Comment: Hi there. This worked perfect. But what is the meaning of `gf` here? I don't find it in `fugitive` documentation.

Comment: Hey! `gf` means editing the existing file under the cursor in the same window.